# DB transactionality in API exit

Tags: ibm-mq, xa

[This link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc/fa20000_.htm) states that the exit function can operate in the application's unit of work.

Imagine the application starts a UOW:

- `MQPUT` a message to a queue
- Insert a record in table T1 of a DB

Also, we have a `Put_After` exit function that also inserts a record in table T2 of the same DB.

As per the above link WebSphere MQ acting as a XA Transaction Manager, will treat the insertion into T1 and T2 as a single XA transaction.

My question is, will DB2 treat the two insertions as a single transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Whether the inserts are one or two transactions depends on whether both are contained between the same `MQBEGIN` and `MQCOMMIT` calls.  That said, the more you do within an exit the slower and less reliable MQ becomes.  For example, an API exit that copies messages to another queue uses only the resources of the QMgr.

However an API exit that calls a DB traverses the network, possibly including the latency of DNS lookups, creates a TLS session (assuming the DB credentials are to be kept private), authenticates and signs-on to the DB, issues the XA `PREPARE` statements and other XA protocol, performs any inserts, then issues the `COMMIT` and the XA transaction completion.

Now imagine doing that for ***every*** message `PUT` or `GET`.

Also, if any of these actions taking place off the QMgr fails, it definitely kills the transaction, possibly kills the app, and depending on `FASTPATH` and other options, possibly trashes the QMgr.

It would be a ***much*** better design to put the before/after images to a separate MQ queue and have a completely independent program load those into the DB.  This keeps the API calls extremely fast as they remain within MQ.  You might lose only 50% of your throughput instead of 80% ~ 90% as would be the case is every `PUT` or `GET` entailed two external calls from the API exit and all the network traversal.  This technique of offloading messages to a second queue for subsequent upload to the DB is in fact a common approach to posting audit messages.

Comment: Logging the messages async to another queue does not work in our specific case because of certain requirements. It was considered though. The overheads of writing to the DB from the API exit are known. The volumes of MQPUT and MQGET are not very large.

Comment: Make sure the code is thread-safe, re-entrant, rock-solid, system-level quality and to maintain sufficiently deep bench to maintain that code.